# WPF binding to a value from my DataContext

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have a plain "Location" object with a list of string properties (City, Country, Zip, etc.) I want to display, underneath headers of the name of the property. What I've got now works, and looks like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="City" Style="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding City}" />
<TextBlock Text="Country" Style="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Country}" />
```

… and so on. The header text happens to be the same as the property path, and naturally I want to avoid duplicating writing all these pairs of TextBlocks and instead use an ItemsControl and DataTemplates.

I've defined a list of strings in my Window.Resources, and have an ItemsControl displaying at least the headers correctly, but I can't use a dynamic value for a binding path:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <x:Array x:Key="LocationKeys" Type="sys:String">
        <sys:String>City</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Country</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Zip</sys:String>
    </x:Array>
</Window.Resources>
```

...

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{StaticResource LocationKeys}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path={Obviously I can't do this}}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
<ItemsControl>
```

So close! I can't shake the feeling that I'm missing something here, and I'm having enough trouble finding the terms to search for to find someone with the same problem - all the hits I'm getting so far for 'Dynamic binding path' etc. are usually trying to solve another problem that's quite different.

Am I missing something easy? Is there a better way?

Comment: You may bind the ItemsSource to a `Dictionary<string, string>` and use `Key` and `Value` in the ItemTemplate.

Comment: I got so tied up trying to do things the WPF way with Shared Resources I couldn't see the wood for the trees - thanks! This looks like the easiest way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view model may contain a dictionary like

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public Dictionary<string, object> Locations { get; }
        = new Dictionary<string, object>();
}
```

to which you would bind like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Locations}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" Width="100"/>
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding Value}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```